# Can not retrieving friends information using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is some testing code:

```
<script> 
  var movieList = new Array();
  var friendList=" ";
  var friendCount = 0;

function get_friend_likes() {
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
    friendCount = response.data.length;
    for( i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
      friendId = response.data[i].id;
      friendList=friendList+(response.data[i].name)+'<br/>';//store names
      FB.api('/'+friendId+'/movies', function(result) {
        movieList = movieList.concat(result.data); //fetch data to the pool
        friendCount--;
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = friendCount 
          + " friends to go ... ";
      });//end_FB.api
    } //end_for

  });//end_FB.api
  }
</script>
```

The problem is: I can get the friends' names and ids successfully with the outer FB.api call, but I can't get '/movies' information in the inner FB.api call. The returned data is empty.
Any insights on this? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [User object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) api documentation you need the "user_likes" permission to get */me/movies* and "friends_likes" permission to get *friendId/movies*.

Have you asked for these permissions?
Not sure how you authenticate your users, but you can do it with the [javascript sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) as well:

```
FB.login(callbackFunction, { scope: "user_likes,friends_likes" });
```